# How to change chat room access?

Tags: support, chat

I am Owner of this chat room the [link](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6137/) . The Room's title is in my native Gujarati(Indian) Language. When I created this chat room, I put public access rights on it. Now I want to change its access rights to Private, so how can I change its access rights?  It is showing only one option button with text "Public" on the page.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your rooms must be publicly readable. Private rooms are only used by moderators for specific purposes.

[If you have 1000 reputation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/gallery-chat-rooms) you can make your chat room publicly read-only by enabling the "gallery" setting in the *access* tab for that chat room.

[image]

Comment: thanks for reply,  but I can not see that Gallary option now. is it disabled for me ?

Comment: @Lucifer Oops, I forgot: [this requires 1000 reputation](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/gallery-chat-rooms).

Comment: you mean for that Gallary Option, I need 1000 Reputation ?

Comment: @Lucifer : Yes.

Comment: Thank you Sir, this information was very useful for me.